# Compare array key, if true display the value PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to compare the array key with another array, and if they are the same, I need to display the value of that key.

This is my array.

```
$events = array( 0 => var1,
                 1 => var2,
                 2 => var3 
               );
```

Lets assume that the $get_date is the key and the $get_name is the value, I want to compare the $get_date to another value, IF TRUE, it will display the value of the combine array. Just ignore the array_combine, they still have the same output anyway. Ignore also the variable used.

```
       $events = array_combine($get_date, $get_name);
    for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
    {
        /* this is where I want the comparing to be done.
        /* this is the confusing part. Not sure what to do.
    }
```

Comment: What are to trying to do compare an array key with a variable value or compare two arrays?

Comment: compare the array keys to the values inside that for loop

Comment: You have to show the source data and the desired result at least.

Comment: so you are trying to see whether the loop index are present as array keys

Comment: yes,. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `array_key_exists`

```
$result =array();
for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++){
   if (array_key_exists($i, $events)) {
          $result[] = $events[$i];
   }
}
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/115175)